# from OWL to Prolog code

Tags: prolog, owl, xsb

I have a owl ontology and I would use prolog rules and XSB to make inference. I know that the THEA library helps to convert owl code into prolog but no examples are available .
So could anybody help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you ask questions please give as much information and detail as possible. What did you allready try? What tutorials/examples and other documentation did you read?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have a meta answer. You might try your question on the mail list for the cliopatria SPARQL server, at cliopatria.swi-prolog.org

Comment: As posed, this is probably off-topic for StackOverflow, since "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  Are you having a particular problem using THEA to do this?  What have you tried?

Comment: This is actually an area I've been doing some work in lately, and I've been using the OWLAPI to traverse class definitions and generate some Prolog style rules.  Prolog can't capture the semantics of all OWL expressions (or, more generally, Description Logic class expressions), but there's been work on Description Logic Programming and on Horn Description Logic, that you might be interested in.  You might also have better luck with this question on http://answers.semanticweb.com.

Comment: Thank you very much Anniepoo and Joshua Taylor

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I used the semweb library of swi-prolog and it runs perfectly